# IE 11 does not show Listbox Items

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, w3c, wai-aria

I would like display combobox on IE 11 by referring this article https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/combobox/aria1.0pattern/combobox-autocomplete-none.html
but for some reason i can not display the listbox items on IE but for other browsers it works fine. Any idea?

If I try to remove this line

```
this.domNode = domNode;
```

it shows me the list but not clickable.

javascript class

```
/*
*   This content is licensed according to the W3C Software License at
*   https://www.w3.org/Consortium/Legal/2015/copyright-software-and-document
*/
var Option = function (domNode, listboxObj) {

  this.domNode = domNode;
  this.listbox = listboxObj;
  this.textContent    = domNode.textContent;
  this.textComparison = domNode.textContent.toLowerCase();

};

Option.prototype.init = function () {

  if (!this.domNode.getAttribute('role')) {
    this.domNode.setAttribute('role', 'option');
  }

  this.domNode.addEventListener('click',      this.handleClick.bind(this));
  this.domNode.addEventListener('mouseover',  this.handleMouseover.bind(this));
  this.domNode.addEventListener('mouseout',   this.handleMouseout.bind(this));

};

/* EVENT HANDLERS */

Option.prototype.handleClick = function (event) {
  this.listbox.setOption(this);
  this.listbox.close(true);
};

Option.prototype.handleMouseover = function (event) {
  this.listbox.hasHover = true;
  this.listbox.open();

};

Option.prototype.handleMouseout = function (event) {
  this.listbox.hasHover = false;
  setTimeout(this.listbox.close.bind(this.listbox, false), 300);
};
```

HTML

```
<section>
      <h2 id="ex_label">Example</h2>
      <div role="separator" id="ex_start_sep" aria-labelledby="ex_start_sep ex_label" aria-label="Start of"></div>
      <div id="ex1">
        <div class="combobox-list">
          <label for="cb1-input">Search</label>
          <div class="group">
            <input id="cb1-input" class="cb_edit" type="text"
                   role="combobox"
                   aria-autocomplete="none"
                   aria-expanded="false"
                   aria-haspopup="true"
                   aria-owns="cb1-listbox"
                   readonly 
            />
            <button id="cb1-button" tabindex="-1" aria-label="Open">
              &#9661;
            </button>
          </div>
          <ul id="cb1-listbox" role="listbox" aria-label="Previous Searches">
            <li id="lb1-01" role="option">weather</li>
            <li id="lb1-02" role="option">salsa recipes</li>
            <li id="lb1-03" role="option">cheap flights to NY</li>
            <li id="lb1-04" role="option">dictionary</li>
            <li id="lb1-05" role="option">baseball scores</li>
            <li id="lb1-06" role="option">hotels in NY</li>
            <li id="lb1-07" role="option">mortgage calculator</li>
            <li id="lb1-08" role="option">restaurants near me</li>
            <li id="lb1-09" role="option">free games</li>
            <li id="lb1-10" role="option">gas prices</li>
            <li id="lb1-11" role="option">classical music</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div role="separator" id="ex_end_sep" aria-labelledby="ex_end_sep ex_label" aria-label="End of"></div>
    </section>
```

Comment: I made a test with your sample code and I am able to produce the issue with IE 11 but did not get any reason why it is not working for IE. I suggest you to make a test with ARIA 1.2 version or try to contact ARIA W3C support. In their documentation, they had mentioned that some code may not work as expected with some browsers. Ref: https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.2/#browser_and_AT_support

Comment: yeah i was trying to make sure if its from my side or not. Thanks

Comment: Is the issue got solved? If no, Is there any progress? Please try to provide the current status of the issue. We will try to provide further suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: no it does not solved. Even the same example on their website it is not working.

Comment: Did you got any information from ARIA W3C support? If yes than you can try to share it here. It can help other community members to come know about the reason for the cause and we can try to narrow down the issue using that.

Comment: no unfortunately no answer.. @Deepak-MSFT

Comment: Thanks for updating the status of the issue.